# Background youtube player

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I am trying to make a Chrome extension such that to play songs from youtube. I have done this but I have a small problem. When I click the extension icon, a popup appears where I can search the song and play it, but when the popup disappears, the music stops playing. What can I do to make the music play in the background?
Here is the function that finds the song, and inserts iframe tag into my popup.html page

```
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = response;
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = responseString.items[0].id.videoId;
    var videoId = responseString.items[0].id.videoId;
    var iFrame = '<iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '"></iframe>';
    document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = iFrame;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to know what is going on without some context.  Can you post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the popup closes, the page that it contains is immediately and completely *unloaded*.

So your iframe is destroyed. And no, you can't keep the popup open.

An extension has one persistent page - the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). You can try adding your iframe there - the sound should continue to play.

However, the page is invisible - you can't let the user control the player. Any user-accessible controls will need to be in the popup or some other UI.